# pecl xmldiff unable to load in apache

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, xmldiff

I can't load xmldiff to apache

pecl install xmldiff did not throw any errors BUT

I error get in apache error.log is :

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xmldiff.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xmldiff.so: undefined symbol:
_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE in Unknown on line 0
```

dynamic links look ok (at least to me )

```
ldd /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xmldiff.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf57fe000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xb75b3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7590000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb73eb000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb73e5000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb73cf000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb73a3000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb771c000)
```

How can I fix or troubleshoot it ?

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask, I think Super User is a better place. Also the error you are seeing appears to be cause your Apache or Module were compiled "manually" while the other was installed from a dpkg package.

Comment: I'll try my luck in Super User as well thanks. As for your comment regarding manual vs dpgk installations - why this should be a problem? I don't see any failures in ldd - seems like everything is linked correctly.

Comment: it could be that one is expecting to find the files in directory A, while the other in directory B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Huge thanks to the maintainer of the xmldiff for php - Anatol Belski!**

> The issue seems to be a configuration one, for some reason it doesn't
>   link against libstdc++. Anatol commited a fix to config.m4, in the
>   current trunk. phpize && ./configure --with-xmldiff && make should be
>   enough to build, then when you check on ldd and see a line like
>
> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
>   (0x00007fe96d363000)
>
> the extension was loaded without errors.